# How to store for loop result as an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I want to store for loop results as an array. The code repeats the results. Kindly correct me.

I did it on While loop it works perfectly.

```
$numbers=array();
$i=23;
   while ($i <= 42){
            if($i % 2 == 0){

            $numbers[] = $i;                    
            }
    $i++;
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($numbers);
        echo ' </pre>';
```

For loop code:

```
$numbers=array();
    for ($i==23; $i<=42; $i++){
        if (!($i % 2)){
            $numbers[]=$i;
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($numbers);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just write it *exactly* the same way as your `while` loop i.e. in your first code replace `$i=23;  while ($i <= 42){` with `for ($i==23; $i<=42; $i++){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change $i == 23 to $i = 23 and move echo to outside for loop.

```
$numbers=array();
for ($i=23; $i<=42; $i++){
    if (!($i % 2)){
        $numbers[]=$i;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($numbers);
echo '</pre>';
```

You will get same result with while loop.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 24
    [1] => 26
    [2] => 28
    [3] => 30
    [4] => 32
    [5] => 34
    [6] => 36
    [7] => 38
    [8] => 40
    [9] => 42
)
```

Comment: Solved! great help.